# "Someone or other" vs "someone"

Tags: vocabulary, phrasal-verbs

Does "someone or other" have the exact same meaning that "someone"? I don't see a difference in these two sentences:

a) Someone or other broke that window.

b) Someone broke that window.

Why would one use "someone or other" instead?

PS I guess the same question is valid for "somehow or other" and "somewhere or other".

Comment: I don't recall ever haring the phrase "someone or other".  Using "something or other" when referring to _things_ is common.

Comment: @JohnGordon, "However little known the feelings or views of such a man may be on his first entering a neighbourhood, this truth is so well fixed in the minds of the surrounding families, that he is considered as the rightful property of someone or other of their daughters." - Pride and Prejudice

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"...someone or other" is very close to "someone", but is only used when you want to *emphasize the fact that you don't know who is referred to*, or that you are indifferent to who is referred to.

You could say:

"**Someone or other** broke the lock off the fence gate!"

or

"Stanley just quit, but we'll find **someone or other** to replace him."

But we would not say:

"Someone or other broke the lock off the fence gate, and I know who it was!"

or

"Someone or other needs to replace Stanley, and I am that someone or other!"